# Locally riskless

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, quantitative, black-scholes-pde

Most derivations of the Black-Scholes formula end up with the following dynamics of some (hedged) portfolio:

$$
\int_{t=0}^{T} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(S(t),t)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(S(t),t)\cdot\sigma^2\cdot S(t)^2\right) \,dt
$$

The process is still **random** because it has stochastic processes as integrands, but the fact that the diffusion term is zero makes it *locally riskless*.

On the other hand, this is not an Itô integral, but a pathwise Riemann integral. Therefore, nothing precludes me from expressing the integral as right Riemann Sums:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(S(t_i^n),t_i^n)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(S(t_i^n),t_i^n)\cdot\sigma^2\cdot S(t_i^n)^2\right) \,*(t_i^n-t_{i-1}^n)
$$

The stochastic process whose integrals are of the form within the limit operation are clearly not locally riskless since at every instance, knowledge about the future is required. How to reconcile this?

Comment: AFAIK locally riskless means the thing within parenthesis is zero. Not much point in integrating it over time. Instead we set the thing within parenthesis to zero to form the BS PDE.

Comment: Hi. I think the thing within parenthesis is not zero and is set to equal to interest rate times the hedged portfolio to form the BS PDE. However, in order to that, the reason given is that it is locally riskless. The integral is the way the dynamics of the stochastic process of the hedged portfolio is usually expressed (though the integral is omitted for presentation purposes).